# Why does one loop style give me an error but the other doesn't?

Tags: typescript, loops, for-loop, node-pg-pool

**Preface**: I am using typescript and node-pg (Postgres for node) to populate an array of promises and then execute them all using `Promise.all()`.

When iterating over an array of numbers and pushing queries into an array, I get an error if I loop over the number array using this code:

```
const gameIds = [1,2,3,4,5];
let queryArray = [];
const sql = 'select bettor, fader from wagers where game_id=$1';
gameIds.forEach((gameId: number)=> {
   // populate the query array
   queryArray.push(DatabaseOperations.dbConnection.query(sql, [gameId]));
});
let allWagersForGames = await Promise.all(queryArray);
```

this code gives me an error when assigning the results of the promise array to `allWagersForGames`. The error states: `Variable 'queryArray' implicitly has an 'any[]' type.ts(7005)`.

But, when I iterate over the number array the following way, no errors appear and I can not figure out why. I don't see why a change of iteration style should affect whether or not the previous error appears:

```
const gameIds = [1,2,3,4,5];
const sql = 'select bettor, fader from wagers where game_id=$1';

for (const gameId of gameIds) {
    // populate the query array
    queryArray.push(DatabaseOperations.dbConnection.query(sql, [gameId]));
}

// now retrieve all of the data
let allWagersForGames = (await Promise.all(queryArray));
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a single query using `WHERE game_id IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 )`? That would be a lot faster to run.

Comment: that is a great point, I'm still working on my database skills so I'll change it to that. Thank you! @Dai

Comment: What is the declaration of `queryArray` in the second code example?

Comment: it's the same as the first `let queryArray = []`

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from this line:

```
let queryArray = [];
```

TypeScript will infer the type of `queryArray` as `any[]` because you haven't initialised it with any typed elements that could be used to infer the type of the whole array. By default, TypeScript is configured to not allow [implicit `any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny) types, so this causes your compilation to fail.

If you change that line to something this, to tell TypeScript that although `queryArray` is empty right now you only intend to put numbers in it (for example - if you mean for it to have another type then of course use that instead), then it should fix the issue as it will no longer have an implicit `any` type:

```
let queryArray: number[] = [];
```